# How to make Datatable row clickable and use GET request with result?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have read the documentation and I am able to display the table on my page, but how would I make each row clickable and using a GET request, send the requested data to another page after clicking on a row? I have read other questions on SO, but can't seem to find a solution that would work for me. This is what I have so far. Thank you for any help and effort!

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="scroll">
<thead>

        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Age</th>

</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr> 
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> Placeholder1</td>
        <td> Placeholder2</td>
        <td> Placeholder3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Placeholder1</td>
        <td> Placeholder2</td>
        <td> Placeholder3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Placeholder1</td>
        <td> Placeholder2</td>
        <td> Placeholder3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var table = $('#scroll').dataTable( { "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" } );


   $('#scroll tbody').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){
    var data = table.row(this).data();
    console.log(data);
   })
});
```

Comment: Just have a look at [**this**](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html)

Comment: Oh i didn't see this, I just tried this and still not able to click on the rows..

Comment: I tried using the cdn and import the javascript it asks, and my table is not displayed anymore either.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want to do, but i followed it exactly and now my table is gone and still cant click on anything with a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that mmushtaq linked the documentation to do exactly what I needed. This makes the rows now clickable. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

JQUERY part:

```
$(document).off( "click", "#scroll tbody tr").on( "click", "#scroll tbody tr", function(){
    var i = 0;
    var query = "";
    $(this).find("td").each(function(){
        query += "columns[" + i++ + "]=" + $(this).text + "&";
    })
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "script.php",
       data: query,
       success: function(){
         alert ("Successfully sent");
       }
    })
})
```

PHP part (script.php)

```
<?php
   $columns = $_POST["columns"];
   foreach ($columns as $index => $value)
   {
     // do something with column # $index and text value is $value
   }
?>
```

Comment: For some reason, applying this code, the rows are still not clickable.

Comment: ?? I believe you mean `$('#scroll').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(){ `...`$(document).off("#scroll tbody tr", "click")` does not make so much sense, and why turn noneexisting events `off`?

Comment: i always turn off events before on. just a habit

Comment: Okay i changed it to your new edits, but Im still not able to click on the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = table.row(this).data();
```

This return the row object so you need to change 
`console.log(data);` 
to 
`console.log(data[0] + " " + data[1] + " " + data[2]);`

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't work for me either. Still not able to click on the row and get an alert.